# Unable to connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-router

I have a Dell Latitude E6530, running Windows 8.1, with a Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter.  I am able to connect to my phone's personal hotspot, but not my home wifi.  The home wifi router is a Google Fiber router, running at 5/2.4 ghz.  The message I get when attempting to connect is "Can't connect to this network."  The Windows troubleshooters don't find anything wrong.  If I disable the security on the router, I'm able to connect to the router, but I have no Internet connectivity.

All of the other devices in my house are able to connect without a problem.  Any ideas are much appreciated.

**Updated.**

Comment: You mention Wifi, but have given me the name of a gigabit ethernet adapter which isn't wifi, but wired. Can you confirm your wireless card please?

Comment: How embarrassing!  I've updated the question with the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably should have thought of this earlier, but the answer was simply to update the driver for the wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually adding a wireless profile with the wireless settings from the router. Quite often the wireless wizard in windows fails to detect the encryption, so manually adding a wireless profile gets around this.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work, despite ensuring that the manually setup profile had the exact same security (WPA2-Personal) as the router.

Comment: Try all the other security methods. WPA, and WPA2. Don't use WEP as it's totally insecure. If still no joy buy a cheap USB wireless adapter and try that. One minor thing - try connecting to the router a room or two away. I did have a router once which TX rate was too high and I could only connect doing this.